# start android emulator with full details instead -avd

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu

I can start the android emulator like this

```
emulator -avd testdevice
```

Is there a way how I can translate this call into exactly the same call with all details given at the cli:

```
emulator -sysdir $ANDROID_TARGET/images 
-kernel $ANDROID_TARGET/images/kernel-qemu 
-datadir $ANDROID_AVD 
-ramdisk $ANDROID_TARGET/images/ramdisk.img 
-system $ANDROID_TARGET/images/system.img 
-data $ANDROID_AVD/userdata-qemu.img 
-cache $ANDROID_AVD/cache.img 
-sdcard $ANDROID_AVD/sdcard.img 
-snapstorage $ANDROID_AVD/snapshots.img 
-no-snapshot-load 
-noskin 
-show-kernel
```

Comment: I think you are missing the `-avd testdevice`. try calling `emulator -avd testdevice -sysdir ...`

Comment: that's what I want to replace. I want to start an emulator without a predefined avd. I know it's possible. I don't know how to find out what options I have to chose according to the settings in the avd.